# Crop image to a fixed width and height ratio using html 5 canvas without uploading image to server before form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form that collects data from multiple text fields and also on the same form is a an input file field for selecting an image.

I have already written the codes to insert the information from the text fields into the database and at the same time, resize the image fro the input field and store it in a folder on the server and store the filename in the database. And at the same time create a thumbnail of the image to be used on the front end of the site that the visitors see.

Now the issue is, the image is resized to a fixed width but resizing to a fixed height means the image is either shrunk for portrait images or stretched for landscape images. I thought of using html 5 canvas to specify the area of the image i want and i have read a ton of samples but they crop and upload the image immediately after cropping. Or they upload before cropping.

What i want to do is  to have the input field select the image and the user immediately select the area needed to crop from the image. Then he is able to fill other form fields and then when he hits the submit button, all form fields are then processed.

An example of what i am trying to archive can be seen in the form example in this link
http://codecanyon.stbeets.nl/

Any help is much needed. Below is my working code without the cropping:

The Php part:

```
<?php

session_start();

function getExtension($str) {

         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; } 

         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

 define ("MAX_SIZE","2048");
    $errors=0;

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    //get form details and check for sql injections and disable them
    $ptitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($connKriticx, $_POST['title']);
    $ptitle = stripslashes($ptitle);
    $pdetail1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connKriticx, $_POST['detailsec1']);
    $pdetail1 = str_ireplace('\r\n', '', $pdetail1);
    $pphoto1 = $_FILES["photo1"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'];
    $pphotocredit1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connKriticx, $_POST['photocredit1']);
    $pphotocredit1 = stripslashes($pphotocredit1);


    $query_Admipdetails = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '" . $_SESSION['User'] . "' LIMIT 1";
    $result_Admipdetails = mysqli_query($connKriticx, $query_Admipdetails);
    $row_Admipdetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_Admipdetails);
    $totalRows_Admipdetails = mysqli_num_rows($result_Admipdetails);

    $userFirstname = $_SESSION["FirstName"];
    $userLastname = $_SESSION["LastName"];


    $pauthor = $userFirstname." ".$userLastname;


    if ($pphoto1){

        $filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($connKriticx, $_FILES['photo1']['name']);
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);

        // Check if file was uploaded
        if(!isset($_FILES['photo1']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'])){
            exit('No file uploaded or Your image has exceeded the size limit of 2Mb. Click the back button on your browser to re-enter the right size of image.');
        }
        if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif"))
        {
            echo ' Unknown Image extension ';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
            $size=filesize($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name']);

            if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
            {
                echo "Your image has exceeded the size limit";
                $errors=1;
            }

            if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
            {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
            }
            else if($extension=="png")
            {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
            }
            else 
            {
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
            }

            list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);



            if ($width > 900) {

            $newwidth=900;  
            $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
            $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

            imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

            $thumbnewwidth=290;
            $thumbnewheight=($height/$width)*$thumbnewwidth;
            $thumbtmp=imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnewwidth,$thumbnewheight);

            imagecopyresampled($thumbtmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$thumbnewwidth,$thumbnewheight,$width,$height);
            }else{

            $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);      
            imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$width,$height);

            $thumbnewwidth=290;
            $thumbnewheight=($height/$width)*$thumbnewwidth;
            $thumbtmp=imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnewwidth,$thumbnewheight);

            imagecopyresampled($thumbtmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$thumbnewwidth,$thumbnewheight,$width,$height);
            }

            $set['photo1'] = "'" . $pphoto1 . "'";      
            $kaboom1 = explode(".", $pphoto1);
            $pixExt1 = end($kaboom1);
            $photo1= rand()."_".time().".".$pixExt1;

            $target1 = "../postsimages/". $photo1;
            $thumbtarget1 = "../postsimages/thumbs/". $photo1;

            imagejpeg($tmp,$target1,100);
            imagejpeg($thumbtmp,$thumbtarget1,75);

            imagedestroy($src);
            imagedestroy($tmp);
            imagedestroy($thumbtmp);
        }
    }

    if ((isset($_POST["form_insert"])) && ($_POST["form_insert"] == "adpostsadd")) {

        date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $stmt = $connKriticx->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (ptitle, pauthor, pdetail1, pphoto1, pphotocredit1, pdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $ptitle, $pauthor, $pdetail1, $photo1, $pphotocredit1, $date);
        $results = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if($results){
            $updateGoTo = "confirm.php"; 
            $errorGoTo = "error.php";
            if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
                $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
                $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            }
            header("Location: ". $updateGoTo);
        }else{
                header("Location: ". $errorGoTo);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The html form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>.:: Posts ::.</title>
<link href="css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="headercont"><?php include('header.php'); ?></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="bodycont">
            <div class="subheadercont">POSTS</div>
            <div class="subbodycont">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <form method="POST" id="adpostsadd" autocomplete="on" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="adpostsadd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="h1">Title:</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="input-field-login2"><input name="title" type="text" required class="std_textbox2" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title" tabindex="1"></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="h1">Detail:</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="std_textbox2"><textarea name="detailsec1" cols="120" rows="6" required class="input-field-textarea" id="detailsec1" placeholder="Enter Detail" tabindex="1" type="text"></textarea></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>                    
                    <div class="h1">Select Photo:</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" />
                    <input name="photo1" type="file" id="photo1" size="26"/>
                    Must not be more than 2Mb in size!!!
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="h1">Photo Credit:</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="input-field-login2"><input name="pphotocredit1" type="text" class="std_textbox2" id="pphotocredit1" placeholder="Enter Photo Credit1" tabindex="1"></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="text2">
                    <div style="width: 285px;">
                      <div class="login-btn3">
                        <button name="login" type="submit" id="login_submit" tabindex="3">Add Post</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div id="divline"></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="text2"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">&laquo; Back</a></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>  
                </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_insert" value="adpostsadd">
                </form>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“An example of what i am trying to archive can be seen in the form example in this link”_ – that page offers this as a downloadable plugin - so what more do you need …?

Comment: I want to understand and know how it was done. I want to learn coding it myself with help of course. Might need to implement it a different way later on. So understanding or learning how it was done is a plus not just implementing already done plugin.

Comment: Fair enough - but then you’ll have to ask us specific questions about specific problems you’re facing.